# Terminal is inputing random stuff

Tags: c, terminal, lexical-analysis

I'm making a lexical analyzer in C that should work the following way:

```
Input : 2 + 3
Output: 
       Token text (Operand): 2
       Token text: +
       Token lexical Category: ADD 
       Token text (Operand): 3
       Token text: -
       Token lexical Category: MINUS
```

The code is this one:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void token(char c);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    if(argc == 1){
        printf("[*] Usage ./%s <TextToAnalyze>\n", argv[0]); //The arguments that the users inputs will be analyzed
    } else{
        char arguments[argc];
        
        for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
            strcat(arguments, argv[i]);//Arguments will be copied and separated to the variable "arguments"
            strcat(arguments, " ");
        }
        
        for( int i = 0; i < strlen(arguments); ++i){
        token(arguments[i]); //Going though the elements of the input as they will be analyzed with the function token
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void token(char c){
    if(isdigit(c)){
        printf("Token text (OPERAND): %c\n", c);
        
    } else if(isalpha(c)){
        printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
        printf("Token lexical category: CHARACTER\n");
    } else if(isspace(c)){
asm ("nop");
    } else {
        
        switch(c){
            case '+':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: ADD\n");
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: SUBTRACT\n");
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: MULTIPLY\n");
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: DIVIDE\n");
                break;
            case '%':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: MODULE\n");
                break;
            case '<':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: LESS THAN\n");
                break;
            case '>':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: GREATER THAN\n");
                break;
            case '=':
                printf("Token text: %c\n", c);
                printf("Token lexical category: EQUAL\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Operator not found: %c \n", c);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever i run it and give the input into the terminal random characters and operands pop up. I made it so the code prints them to show what they are. This is the output i get: (I inputed -2)

```
bash-3.2$ ./a.out - 2
Operator not found:  
Token text: Y
Token lexical category: CHARACTER
Operator not found: ? 
Operator not found: ? 
Operator not found: ? 
Operator not found:  
Token text: -
Token lexical category: SUBTRACT
Token text (OPERAND): 2
bash-3.2$
```

Does anybody know what is happening ?

Comment: Why do you use `asm("nop");` while you could simply do `return;`. I think that's more on the C side.

Comment: Also note that you're allocating memory only for `argument[argc]`, i.e. no. of arguments passed, while it should atleast be no. of arguments passed multiplied by no. of character's in an argument.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot concatentate to an uninitialised array. But a VLA cannot be initialised in its definition, so you would need

```
char arguments[argc];
arguments[0] = '\0';
```

before the first `strcat` can take place. But there is more: `argc` is the number of arguments, not their total length, so

```
char arguments[argc];
```

will be far too short and *will* overflow, you have not prevented that. First you need to calculate what the string length will be:

```
size_t len = 1;                    // for terminator
for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    len += strlen(argv[i]) + 1;    // + 1 for each space separator
}
char arguments[len];
arguments[0] = '\0';
```

and now you can use `strcat` to build the string